# Query a column where column value could be anything in an array

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am using amazons SimpleDB.
My question is simple. I have an array say `[1,2,3,4]`. I need to query my domain in a manner so that if a particular column's value is in this array that row should be selected.

Is this possible or do I have to write multiple query and run a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IN Function

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]  WHERE [COLUMN_NAME] IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

Comment: Actually I had thought of this.
But in simpleDB this does not work.
I have found a workaround for this.
The array should be written as ('1','2','3','4').

Comment: O Yes!!... I just forgot applying these quotes :)